# Expanding flex objects separately with js

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got 3 bootstrap cards with some text and a button to show some more text. These cards have display:flex since they all have different text, but i wanted them to have the same height. Upon showing more text on one card, all three cards expand. Which makes total sense since it has the display:flex. But is there any way i can have the cards the same height when all are closed, and just one expand with the show more button?

I created a gif to further show my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Eve.jpg

Here is my js and and my html:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    var elem = $("#toggle").text();
    if (elem == "Mehr Lesen") {
      $("#toggle").text("Weniger anzeigen");
      $("#text").slideDown(50);
    } else {
      $("#toggle").text("Mehr Lesen");
      $("#text").slideUp( 50);
    }
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle1").click(function() {
    var elem = $("#toggle1").text();
    if (elem == "Mehr Lesen") {
      $("#toggle1").text("Weniger anzeigen");
      $("#text1").slideDown(50);
    } else {
      $("#toggle1").text("Mehr Lesen");
      $("#text1").slideUp( 50);
    }
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle2").click(function() {
    var elem = $("#toggle2").text();
    if (elem == "Mehr Lesen") {
      $("#toggle2").text("Weniger anzeigen");
      $("#text2").slideDown(50);
    } else {
      $("#toggle2").text("Mehr Lesen");
      $("#text2").slideUp(50);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 class="test-header">Was unsere Kunden sagen</h1>
  <h2 class="test-header2">Das Reshape your Body Konzept hat schon für so viele Menschen funktioniert, es wird auch für dich funktionieren.</h2>
  <div class="row row-padding">
    <div class="col-lg-4 card-flex mx-auto">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">Andrea<span><i class="fas fa-star stars first_star"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></span></h4>
          <p class="card-text read-more-wrap">Mir geht es prima, bin immer statt! Das gab es noch nie bei mir und ich habe mich heut gewogen wieder eins weniger also nun 2,5 kg nach einer Woche.<br><span id="text"> Fantastisch step by
              step aber endlich funktioniert bei mir etwas, was jahrelang nicht funktioniert hat. Bin sehr zufrieden und fühl mich super. Auf geht´s in die 2. Phase</span></p>
          <button class="btn btn-secondary card-btn" id="toggle">Mehr Lesen</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 card-flex mx-auto">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">Daniel<span><i class="fas fa-star stars first_star"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="far fa-star stars"></i></span></h4>
          <p class="card-text read-more-wrap">Ich muss wirklich sagen das ich sehr skeptisch gegenüber dem Konzept gewesen bin. Wahrscheinlich weil ich schon so viel ausprobiert hatte. Jetzt, nach 8 Wochen habe ich 9,3 Kilo auf der Waage
            runter.
            <br><span id="text1"> Ich fühle mich einfach unfassbar gut, habe nicht das geringste Bedürfnis zu naschen oder zwischen den Mahlzeiten zu Essen. Das hatte ich wirklich noch NIE!</span></p>
          <button class="btn btn-secondary card-btn" id="toggle1">Mehr Lesen</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 card-flex mx-auto">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">Monika<span><i class="fas fa-star stars first_star"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></span></h4>
          <p class="card-text read-more-wrap">Kurze Info zu meiner Abnehm-Challenge:. Weitere 4 Wochen vorbei und es gibt wieder Gutes zu berichten. Die nächsten 4 Kilos sind verschwunden und das obwohl der ein oder andere "Schlampertag" dabei
            war.<br><span id="text2"> Das Konzept ist genial. Vor allen Dingen für diejenigen, wie ich, die zwar abnehmen wollen aber mit Sport nicht soviel am Hut haben.
            </span></p>
          <button class="btn btn-secondary card-btn" id="toggle2">Mehr Lesen</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm 100% sure there is a better and perhaps easier way of writing that js. But I'm a complete beginner and noob.

That's why I would appreciate every kind of help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: couldn't replicate it - have simplified your code https://jsfiddle.net/rjcua5wy/

Answer (score 0):

Just do a function :)

So the idea is that you create a new function which incapsulates all the logic you need to do each time user presses on title and apply it to each card you have

```
function subscribeOnClick(toggle, mainText, altText, slidingText){
   toggle.click(function() {
    var currentText = toggle.text();
    if (currentText === mainText) {
      toggle.text(altText);
      slidingText.slideDown(50);
    } else {
      toggle.text(mainText);
      slidingText.slideUp(50);
    }
  }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  subscribeOnClick($("#toggle"), 'Mehr Lesen', 'Weniger anzeigen', $("#text"));
  subscribeOnClick($("#toggle1"), 'Mehr Lesen', 'Weniger anzeigen', $("#text1"));
  subscribeOnClick($("#toggle2"), 'Mehr Lesen', 'Weniger anzeigen', $("#text2"));
});
```

Or just remove text arguments, if they are constants.

If the logic is exact the same for each.
Then I would suggest to migrate to classes selectors instead of id's as you do in example and use `data-toggle` attribute instead

```
function subscribeOnClick(){
   $('.toggle').click(function(event) {
    var elem = $(event.target);
    var slidingText = elem.prev().find('.extra-text');
    if(elem.data('expanded')) {
      toggle.text(elem.data('close-text'));
      slidingText.slideDown(50);
    } else {
      toggle.text(elem.data('open-text'));
      slidingText.slideUp(50);
    }
  }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() { subscribeOnClick() })
```

and HTML

```
<div class="card-body">
          ...
          <p class="card-text read-more-wrap">nach ... einer Woche.<br>
             <span class="extra-text"> Fa...die 2. Phase</span>
          </p>
          <button data-show-more="Mehr Lesen" data-show-less="Weniger anzeigen" class="btn btn-secondary card-btn toggle">Mehr Lesen</button>
           ...
</div>
```